# C# Bind DataSet to DataGridView in Windows Form App

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have searched a bunch on this, but the data I'm finding is 5-6 years old, and the 
Bind(); function appears to no longer be valid.

So I have this function that is filling my DataGridView:

```
private void FillTable(string location, string supplier, string item) {
        string sql = "";
        string connString = "<connection info";

        // If ONLY Location is entered
        if (location != "" && supplier == "" && item == "") {
            sql = "SELECT " +
                    "      location_id AS 'Location', " +
                    "      supplier_id AS 'Supplier', " +
                    "      item_id AS 'Item', " +
                    "      recommended_qty_to_order AS 'Recommended Qty'" +
                    "  FROM PorgReqs  " +
                    "  WHERE location_id = @LocationID " +
                    "  ORDER BY supplier_id, item_id";

        }

        // Creates Connection, Sets Variables in Connection and tries to load table
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            // Sets Variables
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationID", txtLocation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierID", txtLocation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", txtLocation.Text);

            // Opens Connection
            conn.Open();

            try 
            {
                // Creates Reader Object
                SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                // Fill the list box with the values retrieved
                if (sqlDataReader.HasRows) 
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(sqlDataReader);
                    //MessageBox.Show(dt.ToString());
                    gridData.DataSource = dt;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    } // End Function
```

The data pulls and loads, however, it is not loading into the columns that I have set:
[image: Column Definitions]

My Grid ends up looking like this:
[image]

My searching says that I need to bind the dataset to the grid, and then I'll be able to set the DataPropertyName for the column so they are loaded correctly.

As a note.  My goal is to load data into the grid, allow editing of the 'addl qty' column, which would reflect on the 'Final Qty' column.  Then the 'Approve' checkbox it clicked it would write info to a separate database that would then be processed when the 'Purchase' button is clicked.  I thought that the DataGridView control is not the best way to do it, please let me know before I head down a rabbit hole.

Comment: I think I worded this poorly since I didn't quite fully understand a few things.

Comment: It is confusing that you commented... _”… and then I'll be able to set the DataPropertyName for the column so they are loaded correctly”_ … then in the picture of the column properties for the “Location” column… it looks like the columns `DataPropertyName` is set to (none)? The `DataPropertyName` for each column that you want to mate up with the `DataTable` column MUST match…. i.e. the grid columns `DataPropertyName` must match the name of the column in the `DataTable`.

Comment: In addition, you may want to set the grids `AutoGenerateColumns` to false. Then, if the columns from the table don’t show in the grid, chances are good that the `DataPropertyName` does not match the table column name. Can you clarify this discrepancy between your comment and the picture?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to Bind the DataTable to the DataGridView so that the table would be formatted per the Designer, and have the additional columns added.  However, it can't be done.

Instead, I load the DataTable into the DataGridView, and then add the columns needed to the DataGridView.

It isn't the most elegant, but it works...

```
private void FillTable(string location, string supplier, string item) {
        string sql = "";
        string connString = "<connect info>";

        // If ONLY Location is entered
        if (location != "" && supplier == "" && item == "") {
            MessageBox.Show("Only Location");
            sql = "SELECT " +
                    "      location_id AS 'Location', " +
                    "      supplier_id AS 'Supplier', " +
                    "      item_id AS 'Item', " +
                    "      recommended_qty_to_order AS 'Rec Qty'" +
                    "  FROM PorgReqs  " +
                    "  WHERE location_id = @LocationID " +
                    "  ORDER BY supplier_id, item_id";

        }

        // Creates Connection, Sets Variables in Connection and tries to load table
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            // Sets Variable
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationID", txtLocation.Text);

            // Opens Connection
            conn.Open();

            try 
            {
                // Creates Reader Object
                SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                // Fill the list box with the values retrieved
                if (sqlDataReader.HasRows) {
                    // Create DataTable
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    // Add Columns to DataTable
                    dt.Columns.Add("Location");
                    dt.Columns.Add("Supplier");
                    dt.Columns.Add("Item");
                    dt.Columns.Add("Rec Qty");
                    dt.Load(sqlDataReader);

                    gridData.DataSource = dt;


                    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn txtAddlQty = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                    txtAddlQty.Name = "AddlQty";
                    txtAddlQty.HeaderText = "Add'l Qty";
                    txtAddlQty.Width = 75;
                    gridData.Columns.Insert(4, txtAddlQty);

                    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn txtFinalQty = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                    txtFinalQty.Name = "FinalQty";
                    txtFinalQty.HeaderText = "Final Qty";
                    txtFinalQty.Width = 75;
                    gridData.Columns.Insert(5, txtFinalQty);

                    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cboAction = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                    cboAction.Name = "Action";
                    cboAction.HeaderText = "Action";
                    cboAction.Items.AddRange("Buy", "Transfer", "Not Buy");
                    cboAction.Width = 75;
                    gridData.Columns.Insert(6, cboAction);

                    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chkApprove = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
                    chkApprove.Name = "Approve";
                    chkApprove.HeaderText = "Approve";
                    chkApprove.Width = 50;
                    gridData.Columns.Insert(7, chkApprove);

                    gridData.Columns["Location"].Width = 60;
                    gridData.Columns["Supplier"].Width = 60;
                    gridData.Columns["Item"].Width = 125;
                    gridData.Columns["Rec Qty"].Width = 75;

                    // Adds default value to the Action column
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gridData.Rows) {
                        row.Cells["Action"].Value = "Buy";
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    } // End Function
```